# JSON field interpretation

Tags: json, api, date, time, rest

I am looking at an API response that shows the profile of the user (Chess Players) on lichess.org. Here, I came up with a field `seenAt = {someNumber}` and `createdAt = 1505668328682` . I am unable to interpret the value and How to use it? Even I didn't found it in their API docs. Does anyone know what it means?

API link: [API link](https://lichess.org/api/user/nihalsarin2004)

Comment: That is nothing but a timestamp of profile created and seen

Comment: It's a timestamp, you can use `new Date(createdAt)` to parse it